# I try to pass the image from Adapter to the other activity with intent in Kotlin, Android, but ıt does not display. What should I do?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi everyone ı am a new about android kotlin, I just try to pass the image from adapter to the other activity but it does not display. I used the intent code. What should I do ? I shared my adapter and the other activity code so you can see how ı used the intent code,

my adapter;

```
class NoteAdapter(private var titleText: ArrayList<String>, private var image: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {



    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        val itemTitle : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
        val itemImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)


        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->


                val intent = Intent(itemView.context, PastNotesActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("oldTitle", titleText[position])

                intent.putExtra("oldImage", image[position] )

                itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

            }

        }


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemTitle.text = titleText[position]
        Picasso.get().load(image[position]).resize(150,150).into(holder.itemImage)


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return titleText.size

    }
}
```

The other activity code,

```
class PastNotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var selectedPicture: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_past_notes)

        val intent = intent

        val oldTitleName = intent.getStringExtra("oldTitle")

        val oTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pastTitleText)

        oTitle.text = oldTitleName

        val oldImageView:Int = intent.getIntExtra("oldImage", 0)
        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pastImage)
        imageView.setImageResource(oldImageView)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `PastNotesActivity` you are extracting `IntExtra` but you sent `StringExtra`.

Change your code from

```
val oldImageView:Int = intent.getIntExtra("oldImage", 0)
```

To

```
val oldImageView:String = intent.getStringExtra("oldImage", "")
```

Then load the image using `Picasso` as you did in your `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Yes, it works ,thank you. But It should be like that val oldImageView:String = intent.getStringExtra("oldImage")